# framer-motion: How do you share different animations between parent and child components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I was making a navigationbar. 
And I would like to add scale effect and underline effect when mouse is placed on the button.
I made a lower  component in the  component and added animation using framer-motion. 
However, if i mouse over the underline, it works well, but i mouse over the item component, the underline animation effect does not work.
Attempt to resolve with LayoutGroup failed.
plz help..

```js
const itemBtnVariant = {
    normal: {},
    action: {
      scale: 1.2,
    },
    underAction: {
      opacity: 1,
      width: "30px",
    },
  };
```

```js
const Item = styled(motion.li)<{ route: boolean }>`
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

`;
const UnderBar = styled(motion.div)`
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;
```

```js
<Link to={"/"}>
            <LayoutGroup>
              <Item
                layout
                variants={itemBtnVariant}
                initial="normal"
                whileHover="action"
                layoutId="1"
                route={Boolean(homeRoute)}
              >
                Home
                <UnderBar
                  layout
                  variants={itemBtnVariant}
                  initial="normal"
                  layoutId="1"
                  whileHover="underAction"
                />
              </Item>
            </LayoutGroup>
          </Link>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
The key was inheritance.
Make `itemBtnVariant` and `underBarVariant` the same property.
Because animation is inherited from parent to child.
Therefore, you use variants and animations for the parent component and only 
change variants for the child component.

```
 const itemBtnVariant = {
    normal: {
      scale: 1,
    },
    action: {
      scale: 1.2,
    },
  };
  const underBarVariant = {
    normal: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      width: "15px",
    },
    action: {
      opacity: 1,
      width: "30px",
    },
  };
```

```js
              <Item
                variants={itemBtnVariant}
                whileHover="action"
                initial="normal"
                route={Boolean(homeRoute)}
              >
                Home
                <UnderBar variants={underBarVariant} />
              </Item>
```